# Fail to relay email with Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I want to relay mail to local SMTP to mandrillapp, with the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:info@example.com:xxx
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = test123.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [smtp.mandrillapp.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

and in the mail log

```
Apr 22 11:36:33 test123 postfix/pickup[4002]: 2CAA8122694: uid=0 from=<root@test123>
Apr 22 11:36:33 test123 postfix/cleanup[4008]: 2CAA8122694: message-id=<20140422153633.2CAA2938324@test123.example.com>
Apr 22 11:36:33 test123 postfix/qmgr[4003]: 2CAA8122694: from=<root@test123>, size=339, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 22 11:36:33 test123 postfix/smtp[4010]: 2CAA8122694: to=<foobar@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.mandrillapp.com[54.255.70.161]:587, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0/0.02/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 242232323)
Apr 22 11:36:33 test123 postfix/qmgr[4003]: 223232323: removed
```

What would be the reason? I have checked the mandrillapp admin console and also can't find the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things that might be wrong.

As you can see form the logs the message was successfully delivered by Postfix. Something inside Mandrillapp dropped your message or in the final destination, your foobar@gmail.com address.

The from field comes from a non valid FQDN in the domain part. So it's probably blocked on some antispam, perhaps in Mandrillapp or perhaps in Google. Have you checked your spambox in foobar@gmail.com to see if the message has gone there?

Another thing I would do is changing test123 for a domain name that you own, so it will not de blocked, tagged or scored high in spam tests.

If you don't have a FQDN just sent the email as your gmail account authenticating in Google Servers instead.